# Updates are not showing to public (New Posts , Theme Change)

Tags: posts, cache

if do any changes to website like adding New Post and changing theme are not reflecting to public but as a admin changes are showing. For reference please find the attached images.

As a Admin

[image: As a Admin Image]

As a Public User

[image: As_A_Public user]

If i do any changes as a admin it is showing.
How can i solve this issue ?
Please help me.

Comment: are you using something horrible like page caching?

Comment: No we are not using

Comment: are you absolutely sure you're not using caching? I loaded your site, it's very, very fast and loads near-instaneously. That's rare. Unless you've really optimised the speed, if so, congrats.

Comment: I can see that on every page except your homepage, it loads slowly, but shows the correct content. Your homepage is very fast, but the content is wrong. So yes, you're using caching.

Comment: I am using cloudflare but in mobile updated content is coming

Comment: Even if we change the theme that also not reflecting and in category also not showing

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the cloudflare cache after removing site from cloudflare we are getting the updated content.